# Can I reclaim Poker Night 2 unlocked skins in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2, poker-night-2

I just bought a copy of Poker Night 2 and Claptrap brought his bounty onto the deck. I don't have Borderlands 2 yet (not that much into FPS) but I heard it very positive. So if I get Borderlands 2 in the future, can I still get the unlocked skins from Poker Night 2? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can as long as you run borderlands 2 on the same account

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are running both games on the same account and using the same save file for Poker Night 2, you'll be able to access the skins again by going into the Bounties section through the menu.